# How does Sql compare values?

Tags: sql, comparison

Sql has a variety of operands that can check values and return results based on a variety of criteria. The [equals (=)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx) is one of these operands and is defined by Microsoft as something that

> Compares the equality of two expressions

How does sql do this? I would assume that the values being compared are converted to ascii or unciode and these values are compared rather than the user-entered values. However, sql generally defaults to being case insensitive, while ascii, for example, assigns different numberical representations depending on the case. Is there a general method that sql uses for value comparisons? Is the method standard across platforms?

Comment: you'd have to ask microsoft what they do. but a quick/dirty case-insensitive comparison in a system which is otherwise case sensitive can be as simple as `tolower(foo) = tolower(bar)`. maybe mysql uses `toupper` instead. no way to tell, short of looking at the actual source code.

Comment: "Is the method standard across platforms?" - Given the differences in engine behaviour, I'd suggest that this is different across platforms and I would be very surprised to find out otherwise.

Comment: It is more complicated than you think.  The place is start is by understanding collations . . . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators test whether two expressions are the same. Comparison operators can be used on all expressions except expressions of the text, ntext, or image data types. The following below links the Transact-SQL comparison operators.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188074.aspx

OR

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm

Comment: This is not quite what I'm asking. I would like to know how they do the actual comparison internally.